\Drupal::messenger()->addMessage Logs out user automatically
I'm working on a Drupal 10 offsite payment module. I'm trying to show Drupal message whenever order gets placed, declined, or failed. Please see code snippet:
module file: Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Commerce\PaymentGateway\LatpayRedirect.php
  public function onReturn(OrderInterface $order, Request $request) {
  //\Drupal::logger('commerce_payment')->notice('onReturn function called.'); 

    $amount = $request->get('amount');
    $status_code = $request->get('Status');
    $merchant_ref_number = $request->get('merchant_ref_number');
    $currencydesc = $request->get('currencydesc');
    $transaction_id = $request->get('Transactionid');
    $Requestid = $request->get('Requestid');
    $CardLast4 = $request->get('CardLast4');
    $CardType = $request->get('CardType');

    // Concatenate the merchant_ref_number and the last 4 digits
    $remote_id = $merchant_ref_number . '.' . $CardType . ' Card ending in ' . $CardLast4;

    // Create and save payment entity.
    $payment_storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('commerce_payment');
    $payment = $payment_storage->create([
        'state' => 'completed',
        'amount' => $order->getBalance(),
        'payment_gateway' => $this->parentEntity->id(),
        'order_id' => $order->id(),
        'remote_id' => $remote_id,
        'remote_state' => $status_code,
    ]);

    $payment->save(); 

    // Check the status code returned from the payment gateway.
    if ($status_code == '00') {
      // Payment was successful.
        \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($this->t('Your payment was successful. Status Code - @status / Reference number - @merchant_ref_number / Transaction ID - @transaction_id.', ['@merchant_ref_number' => $merchant_ref_number, '@transaction_id' => $transaction_id, '@status' => $status_code]), 'status');  

    }
    elseif ($status_code == '05') {    
    // Transaction Failed / Declined.
 
        \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($this->t('Payment declined. Please try again with correct card details. Status Code - @status / Reference number - @merchant_ref_number / Transaction ID - @transaction_id.', ['@status' => $status_code, '@transaction_id' => $transaction_id, '@merchant_ref_number' => $merchant_ref_number]), 'error');  

      $order->set('state', 'pending');
      $order->save();
 
    }
  }


  public function onCancel(OrderInterface $order, Request $request) {
    $status_code = $request->get('Status');
    //$merchant_ref_number = $request->get('Merchant_ref_number');

     \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($this->t('Status Code : @status / You cancelled before making payment but you may resume the checkout process here whenever you are ready.', [
          '@status' => $status_code,
          //'@merchant_ref_number' => $merchant_ref_number,
        ]), 'error');
  } 

The problem is - it logs out user everytime the order is placed or transaction failed. While performing a test, I commented out those drupal messenger, and it started working fine. It didn't logged me out then. So I knew who the culprit was.
I have been stuck for days. Can someone please help me why this happening and what I could do to resolve or any alternate solution? Thanks a lot.
Update: Here's the thing, for me it's very urgent and I genuinely need help to resolve this issue asap no matter if I have to pay few bucks. So Whoever helps me will get paid with bounty. Please guys!! Help.

What is the precise Drupal version?

Hi, I'm using version 10.2.4.

Try to inject the messenger instead of discouraged \Drupal::...

Already done that, It's not working.

Have you analyzed request and response headers with web browser dev tools?

sorry, but can you pls give more details on what need to be analysed in request and response header in browser dev tool? I'm new to this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603561/how-can-i-debug-a-http-post-in-chrome

Yeah I checked the request and response headers in the dev tool, All looks fine to me.  but how is it related to my question?

So the client sends the session cookie but nevertheless is logged out?

yes, it still gets and I already mentioned in my question. This log out issue only happens when I use \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage. If I comment out that code, log out doesn't happen. You can check my site clicking here https://drupal.latdev.latpay.com.au/

I didn’t see session cookie mentioned in the question. I must have missed that.
